# "Overflow evaluating the requirement" but that kind of recursion should not happen at all

Tags: generics, rust

Here is a kind of lengthy example because I was not able to reduce it further. [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Amarker%3A%3APhantomData%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aops%3A%3A%7BAdd%2C%20Sub%2C%20Mul%2C%20Div%7D%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Scalar%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%20Sized%20%2B%20Copy%20%2B%20Add%3CSelf%2C%20Output%20%3D%20Self%3E%20%2B%20Sub%3CSelf%2C%20Output%20%3D%20Self%3E%20%2B%20Mul%3CSelf%2C%20Output%20%3D%20Self%3E%20%2B%20Div%3CSelf%2C%20Output%20%3D%20Self%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20Scalar%20for%20u32%20%7B%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20ScalarVal%3CT%3E(T)%20where%20T%3A%20Scalar%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Pixel%3A%20Sized%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20ScalarType%3A%20Scalar%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Debug%2C%20Copy%2C%20Clone%2C%20PartialEq)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Gray%3CBaseTypeP%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20BaseTypeP%3A%20Scalar%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20intensity%3A%20BaseTypeP%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CBaseTypeP%3E%20Pixel%20for%20Gray%3CBaseTypeP%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20BaseTypeP%3A%20Scalar%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20ScalarType%20%3D%20BaseTypeP%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CBaseTypeP%3E%20Add%3CGray%3CBaseTypeP%3E%3E%20for%20ScalarVal%3CBaseTypeP%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20BaseTypeP%3A%20Scalar%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Output%20%3D%20Gray%3CBaseTypeP%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20add(self%2C%20rhs%3A%20Gray%3CBaseTypeP%3E)%20-%3E%20Gray%3CBaseTypeP%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unimplemented!()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20struct%20Image%3CPixelP%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20PixelP%3A%20Pixel%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20_marker%3A%20PhantomData%3CPixelP%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CPixelP%3E%20Add%3CImage%3CPixelP%3E%3E%20for%20ScalarVal%3C%3CPixelP%20as%20Pixel%3E%3A%3AScalarType%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20PixelP%3A%20Pixel%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ScalarVal%3C%3CPixelP%20as%20Pixel%3E%3A%3AScalarType%3E%3A%20Add%3CPixelP%2C%20Output%20%3D%20PixelP%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Output%20%3D%20Image%3CPixelP%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20add(self%2C%20rhs%3A%20Image%3CPixelP%3E)%20-%3E%20Image%3CPixelP%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unimplemented!()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20Gray%3A%3A%3Cu32%3E%20%7B%20intensity%3A%2041%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20ScalarVal(1)%20%2B%20a%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ops::{Add, Sub, Mul, Div};

pub trait Scalar
    : Sized + Copy + Add<Self, Output = Self> + Sub<Self, Output = Self> + Mul<Self, Output = Self> + Div<Self, Output = Self>
    {}
impl Scalar for u32 {}

pub struct ScalarVal<T>(T) where T: Scalar;

pub trait Pixel: Sized {
    type ScalarType: Scalar;
}

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Gray<BaseTypeP>
    where BaseTypeP: Scalar
{
    intensity: BaseTypeP,
}

impl<BaseTypeP> Pixel for Gray<BaseTypeP>
    where BaseTypeP: Scalar
{
    type ScalarType = BaseTypeP;
}

impl<BaseTypeP> Add<Gray<BaseTypeP>> for ScalarVal<BaseTypeP>
    where BaseTypeP: Scalar
{
    type Output = Gray<BaseTypeP>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Gray<BaseTypeP>) -> Gray<BaseTypeP> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

pub struct Image<PixelP>
    where PixelP: Pixel
{
    _marker: PhantomData<PixelP>,
}

impl<PixelP> Add<Image<PixelP>> for ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>
    where PixelP: Pixel,
          ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>: Add<PixelP, Output = PixelP>
{
    type Output = Image<PixelP>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Image<PixelP>) -> Image<PixelP> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Gray::<u32> { intensity: 41 };
    let b = ScalarVal(1) + a;
}
```

Can someone explain why I am getting `overflow evaluating the requirement <_ as Pixel>::ScalarType` in that code snippet?

I am confused because:

- If the `Add` implementation in line 44 is removed the code compiles fine. But that implementation should not be used at all => `main()` only uses `Gray` and not `Image`
- The recursion seems to be in nested `Image<Image<...>>` structs but that should not happen at all?!
- If line 46 is changed to `ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>: Add` it compiles fine - But why?

### Some context

This is part of an image processing library I want to build. The idea is to have different pixel formats (Gray, RGB, Bayer, ...) which can be used for images. Therefore you have `Image<Gray>` for a grayscale image. Different `Pixel` implementations can implement different operators, so you can do calculations (e.g. `gray_a = gray_b + gray_c`) with them. It is also possible to use scalar values in those implementations to do e.g. `gray_a = gray_b + ScalarVal(42)`. Because I want to make it possible to have `ScalarVal` as right- **and** left-hand-argument there need to be two implementations (`impl Add<Gray<...>> for ScalarVal<...>` and `impl Add<ScalarVal<...>> for Gray<...>`).

Ok and now the `Image` type should implement all operators which are supported by the used `Pixel` type. If it is possible to do `gray_pixel + Scalar(42)` it should also be possible to do `gray_image + Scalar(42)`.

Hope this kind of makes sense.

Comment: "I was not able to reduce it further" → You don't seem to have tried very hard then. [I got it down to this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=509460c43257a7e046a636fbbcf5fd28&version=stable&backtrace=0) before I called it good enough. That makes the error pretty clear.

Comment: Likewise, I got [it down to this](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=86dcf7126fa905801fb7b37c6dda15e9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ScalarVal(1) + a` resolves basically to `<ScalarVal(1) as Add>.add(a)`, which looks for an `Add` implementation on `ScalarVal`.

For whatever reason, this one is checked first:

```
impl<PixelP> Add<Image<PixelP>> for ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>
    where PixelP: Pixel,
          ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>: Add<PixelP, Output = PixelP>
```

`PixelP` is uninstantiated at this point, so `PixelP: Pixel` can't be checked. Thus we get to

```
ScalarVal<<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType>: Add<PixelP, Output = PixelP>
```

Let's simplify this. Since `PixelP` is unknown right now, `<PixelP as Pixel>::ScalarType` is unknown. The actual information known by the compiler looks more like

```
impl<T> Add<Image<T>> for ScalarVal<_>
    where ScalarVal<_>: Add<T, Output = T>
```

So `ScalarVal<_>` looks for an `Add<T, Output = T>`. This means we should look for an appropriate `T`. Obviously this means looking in `ScalarVal`'s `Add` `impl`s. Looking at the same one, we get

```
impl<T2> Add<Image<T2>> for ScalarVal<_>
    where ScalarVal<_>: Add<T2, Output = T2>
```

which means that *if* this one matches, `T == Image<T2>`.

Obviously then `T2 == Image<T3>`, `T3 == Image<T4>`, etc. This results in an overflow and general sadness. Rust never finds a *disproof*, so can't ever guarantee it's going down the wrong path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That clears things up a bit. I still have a question though: Why is PixelP unknown? Isn't this a type checking problem at the point where `ScalarVal(1) + a` is executed? So it is already known that `a` is `Gray<...>`?! Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @Daniel `PixelP` is unknown because Rust is still checking the `where` clause; it hasn't yet gotten to the `add` method. I don't see any obvious way to solve this, but it's probably solvable with enough work.