# How can I implement std::convert::From such that it does not consume its input?

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

I have managed to make the Rust type checker go into an infinite loop. A very similar program compiles with no trouble. Why does the program I want not compile?

To save your time and effort, I have made minimal versions of the two programs that isolate the problem. Of course, the minimal version is a pointless program. You'll have to use your imagination to see my motivation.

## Success

Let me start with the version that works. The struct `F<T>` wraps a `T`. The type `Target` can be converted from an `F<T>` provided `T` can.

```
struct F<T>(T);

impl<T> From<F<T>> for Target where Target: From<T> {
    fn from(a: F<T>) -> Target {
        let b = Target::from(a.0);
        f(&b)
    }
}
```

Here's an example caller:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Target;
    let y = F(F(F(x)));
    let z = Target::from(y);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

This [runs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Target%3B%0A%0Afn%20f(t%3A%20%26Target)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Pretend%20this%20is%20a%20difficult%20calculation.%0A%20%20%20%20t.clone()%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20F%3CT%3E(T)%3B%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20From%3CF%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20Target%20where%20Target%3A%20From%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from(a%3A%20F%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom(a.0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(%26b)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20Target%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20F(F(F(x)))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom(y)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20z)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) and prints `"Target"`.

## Failure

The function `f` does not consume its argument. I would prefer it if the `From` conversion also did not consume its argument, because the type `F<T>` could be expensive or impossible to clone. I can write a custom trait `FromRef` that differs from [`std::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) by accepting an immutable borrow instead of an owned value:

```
trait FromRef<T> {
    fn from_ref(a: &T) -> Self;
}
```

Of course, I ultimately want to use `From<&'a T>`, but by defining my own trait I can ask my question more clearly, without messing around with lifetime parameters. (The behaviour of the type-checker is the same using `From<&'a T>`).

Here's my implementation:

```
impl<T> FromRef<F<T>> for Target where Target: FromRef<T> {
    fn from_ref(a: &F<T>) -> Target {
        let b = Target::from_ref(&a.0);
        f(&b)
    }
}
```

This compiles. However, the `main()` function doesn't:

```
fn main() {
    let x = Target;
    let y = F(F(F(x)));
    let z = Target::from_ref(y);
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

It [gives a huge error message](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Target%3B%0A%0Afn%20f(t%3A%20%26Target)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Pretend%20this%20is%20a%20difficult%20calculation.%0A%20%20%20%20t.clone()%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20F%3CT%3E(T)%3B%0A%0Atrait%20FromRef%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26T)%20-%3E%20Self%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20FromRef%3CTarget%3E%20for%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26Target)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.clone()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20FromRef%3CF%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20Target%20where%20Target%3A%20FromRef%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26F%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom_ref(%26a.0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(%26b)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20Target%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20F(F(F(x)))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom_ref(%26y)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20z)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0) beginning:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `_: std::marker::Sized`
  --> <anon>:26:13
   |
26 |     let z = Target::from_ref(y);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromRef<F<_>>` for `Target`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromRef<F<F<_>>>` for `Target`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromRef<F<F<F<_>>>>` for `Target`
etc...
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

I've [randomly fixed it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Clone%2C%20Debug)%5D%0Astruct%20Target%3B%0A%0Afn%20f(t%3A%20%26Target)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Pretend%20this%20is%20a%20difficult%20calculation.%0A%20%20%20%20t.clone()%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20F%3CT%3E(T)%3B%0A%0Atrait%20FromRef%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26T)%20-%3E%20Self%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20FromRef%3CTarget%3E%20for%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26Target)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.clone()%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20FromRef%3CF%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20Target%20where%20Target%3A%20FromRef%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from_ref(a%3A%20%26F%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom_ref(%26a.0)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f(%26b)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3D%20Target%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20F(F(F(x)))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20z%20%3D%20Target%3A%3Afrom_ref(%26y)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20z)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)!

The problem was that I forgot to implement `FromRef<Target>` for `Target`.

So I would now like to know: what was the compiler thinking? I still can't relate the problem to the error message.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397157/overflow-evaluating-the-requirement-but-that-kind-of-recursion-should-not-happ

Comment: Looks plausible. I still don't understand my case, though.

Comment: At least two people think some similar behaviour is a compiler bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34137

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid consuming the input in the standard `From`/`Into` traits.

They are defined to always consume the input. Their definition specifies both input and output as owned types, with unrelated lifetimes, so you can't even "cheat" by trying to consume a reference.

- If you're returning a reference, you can implement `AsRef<T>` instead. Or if your type is a thin wrapper/smart pointer, `Deref<T>`. You can provide methods `as_foo()`
- If you're returning a new (owned) object, the convention is to provide `to_foo()` methods.