# Infinite recursion compilation error on a type that is not recursive

Tags: rust

I have a generic trait `Trait<E: Float>`, a generic struct `Struct<E: Float>` for that trait, an implementation of `Mul` for the struct, and a generic function that takes a `Trait` with `Mul`.

```
extern crate num;

use std::ops::Mul;
use num::traits::Float;

trait Trait<E: Float> {}

struct Struct<E: Float> (E);

impl<E: Float> Trait<E> for Struct<E> {}

impl<'a, 'b, E: Float> Mul<&'b Struct<E>> for &'a Struct<E>
    where &'a E: Mul<&'b E, Output=E>
{
    type Output = Struct<E>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Struct<E>) -> Self::Output { unimplemented!() }
}

fn multiply<'a, E: Float, T: Trait<E>>(x: &'a T) -> T
    where &'a T: Mul<&'a T, Output=T>
{
    unimplemented!()
}

fn main() {
    let matrix = multiply(&Struct(1.0));
}
```

There is nothing in here that appears to be recursive. However, the compiler errors by bottoming out the recursion:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `<&_ as std::ops::Mul<&_>>::Output`
  --> src\main.rs:29:18
   |
29 |     let matrix = multiply(&Struct(1.0));
   |                  ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Mul<&Struct<_>>` for `&Struct<_>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Mul<&Struct<Struct<_>>>` for `&Struct<Struct<_>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Mul<&Struct<Struct<Struct<_>>>>` for `&Struct<Struct<Struct<_>>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Mul<&Struct<Struct<Struct<Struct<_>>>>>` for `&Struct<Struct<Struct<Struct<_>>>>`
...
```

Here are some odd facts I have found while debugging and trying to minimize this example:

- If I add `E: Zero` to the type constraints of `Mul`, the stack trace becomes non-deterministic. Sometimes, it will refer to traits that aren't even imported, like `Complex` or `Ratio` where `_` appears.
- It doesn't matter what the constraints are for the the generic parameter `E`. I can create a new trait instead of using `Float` and it does the same thing.
- This only happens if the `Mul` is defined for references, not owned values.

What do I need to do to not lead the compiler down absurd types like `&Struct<Struct<_>>`, etc.?

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397157/overflow-evaluating-the-requirement-but-that-kind-of-recursion-should-not-happ.