# Overflow evaluating the requirement when returning a recursive iterator using impl trait

Tags: recursion, tree, rust, iterator, overflow

I'm trying to iterate depth-first over a tree structure in Rust. I thought I had a really nice concise solution for this, but I can't get it to compile. Conceptually it's pretty simple: iterate over the children, get each child's depth first iterator, flatten them, and chain the current node's metadata iterator to it.

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct Node {
    metadata: Vec<i64>,
    children: Vec<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn depth_first_metadata_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &i64> + '_ {
        self.children
            .iter()
            .map(|child| child.depth_first_metadata_iter())
            .flatten()
            .chain(self.metadata.iter())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree = Node {
        metadata: vec![1, 2, 3],
        children: vec![
            Box::new(Node {
                metadata: vec![4, 5],
                children: vec![],
            }),
            Box::new(Node {
                metadata: vec![6, 7],
                children: vec![],
            }),
        ],
    };
    println!(
        "{:?}",
        tree.depth_first_metadata_iter().collect::<Vec<&i64>>()
    );
}
```

However, when I compile this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `impl std::iter::Iterator`
  |
  = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="128"]` attribute to your crate
```

(You can check this out yourself on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc13c24c2897308cc23124326129af31).)

It makes sense that this would be an error, as I am making recursive calls inside `depth_first_metadata_iter` which return nested iterators, but it would be really nice if something like this code could work without having to implement a custom iterator.

All other solutions to the `E0275` error I have seen (eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196422/what-does-overflow-evaluating-the-requirement-mean-and-how-can-i-fix-it), [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23714), [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39959)) seem to involve strategically placing a type annotation somewhere - is something like that possible here, or am I trying something "impossible"?

Comment: `.map(x).flatten()` => `flat_map(x)`

Comment: added links to other solutions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if something like this code could work

Depends on how "like" you mean. This is similar, works, and doesn't require a custom iterator; thus meeting all of your requirements:

```
fn depth_first_metadata_iter(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item = &i64> + '_> {
    Box::new({
        self.children
            .iter()
            .flat_map(|child| child.depth_first_metadata_iter())
            .chain(self.metadata.iter())
    })
}
```

---

At the heart, this is the same problem as shown in

- [What does "Overflow evaluating the requirement" mean and how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31196422/155423)
- ["Overflow evaluating the requirement" but that kind of recursion should not happen at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39397157/155423)
- [Curiously recurring generic trait pattern: overflow evaluating the requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50657585/155423)

Put yourself in the compiler's shoes for a while. Your original code says "I'm going to return a concrete iterator type, but I'm not going to say the exact type". The compiler still has to be able to figure out that type, so let's be the compiler:

```
let a = self.children.iter();
// std::slice::Iter<'_, Box<Node>>

let cls = |child| child.depth_first_metadata_iter();
// Fn(&Box<Node>) -> ?X?

let b = a.flat_map(cls);
// FlatMap<Iter<'_, Box<Node>>, ?X?, Fn(&Box<Node>) -> ?X?>

let d = self.metadata.iter();
// std::slice::Iter<'_, i64>

b.chain(d);
// Chain<FlatMap<Iter<'_, Box<Node>>, ?X?, Fn(&Box<Node>) -> ?X?>, Iter<'_, i64>>
```

This end result is the return value, so we have our equation:

```
Chain<FlatMap<Iter<'_, Box<Node>>, ?X?, Fn(&Box<Node>) -> ?X?>, Iter<'_, i64>> === ?X?
```

AFAIK, it's impossible to perform the type-level algebra to solve for `?X?`, thus you get the error.

Changing the return type to a boxed trait object short circuits all of the logic needed and forces a specific concrete type.

> strategically placing a type annotation somewhere

I don't believe this to be the case. If so, that would mean that the algebra *is* solvable but that the compiler isn't smart enough to solve it. While this is undoubtedly true in other situations, I don't think it is here.

---

I don't think this is a *great* solution, as this will involve lots of tiny allocations. I'd assume (but have not tested) that a custom iterator using a stack data structure would be more efficient.

A middle ground would be to build up the entire set of nodes:

```
impl Node {
    fn depth_first_metadata_iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &i64> + '_ {
        self.x().into_iter()
    }

    fn x(&self) -> Vec<&i64> {
        fn x_inner<'a>(node: &'a Node, v: &mut Vec<&'a i64>) {
            for c in &node.children {
                x_inner(c, v)
            }
            v.extend(&node.metadata);
        }

        let mut v = Vec::new();
        x_inner(self, &mut v);
        v
    }
}
```

Comment: That's "like" enough for now :) thanks so much for the speedy reply! And duh, should obviously have used `flat_map`.